Homology of complex projective plane with a ball glued to it
Let $\mathbb{C}P^n$ be the complex projective plane, let $B^3$ be a $3$ ball, and suppose we attach $B^3$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1 \subset \mathbb{C}P^n$ using a map $f : \partial B^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ of degree $m$. Let $X = \mathbb{C}P^n \cup_{f} B^3$ be the space obtained from this glueing. I am trying to compute the cohomology groups of $X$.
Here is my attempt, which also leads to an answer, but this topic is so confusing and I have no idea if it makes any sense. There is also a real question at the end.
If we consider cellular homology, then the chain complex will be free abelian groups generated by the number of cells. I think this space has a cellular structure of $\mathbb{C}P^n$, but with one extra $3$ cell, that is,
$$...\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$
Now the attaching map from the $3$ cell to $\mathbb{C}P^1$ has degree $m$, so the complex with the map is
$$...\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{?} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{m}\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$
I belive that this is enough for homology computation, and we get that $H_0 = \mathbb{Z}, H_1 = 0, H_2 = \mathbb{Z}_m, H_3 = 0$ and higher homology groups are as of $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Is this correct? Also, what is the map I marked in "?"? It does not important for homology, but I am not sure how to find it.

That boundary map $\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{?} \mathbb Z$ would be important for homology if it were nonzero, because then $H_4$ would not be the same as it is for $\mathbb C P^n$.
But fortunately for $H_4(\mathbb CP^n)$ which is nervously awaiting its fate, nothing changes, because that map is zero.
To see why, consider the characteristic map $\chi : B^4 \to \mathbb CP^2 \subset \mathbb CP^n$ which determines the $4$-cell, and consider its restriction to the boundary which is $\partial\chi : S^3 \to \mathbb CP^1 \subset \mathbb CP^n$. Notice that this attaching map is the same after you have attached an additional $3$-ball, and so $\text{image}(\partial\chi)$ is disjoint from the image of the interior of the attached 3-ball. This implies that $\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{?} \mathbb Z$ is the zero map.
What you are perhaps missing (and what seems to be unevenly taught in algebraic topology) is how to calculate boundary maps using degree theory. In general, given a CW complex $X$, a $k$-cell $e \subset X^{(k)} \subset X$ with characteristic map $\chi_e : B^k \to X^{(k)}$, and a $k+1$-cell $f \subset X^{(k+1)}$ with characteristic map $\chi_f : B^{k+1} \to X^{(k+1)} \subset X$ and attaching map $\partial\chi_f : S^k \to X^{(k)} \subset X$, that map $\partial\chi_f$ has a well-defined degree over the interior of $e$; call this number $d(f,e)$. With sufficient smoothness, that number is just the ordinary degree over any interior point of $e$ that is a regular point with respect to $\partial\chi_f$. That number $d(f,e)$ is one of the matrix entries of the boundary map from CW $k+1$ chains to CW $k$ chains, namely the boundary map corresponding to the pair $(f,e)$. So if the image of $\partial\chi_f$ completely misses $e$, the degree is $0$, and the corresponding matrix entry is zero.

Thank you. All this discussion about degrees is really confusing for me, and the matrix explanation is not something I saw before. Any recommended source for it?

That's the trouble, it is not well-covered in the algebraic topology textbook literature. Hatcher's book has a good discussion in terms of the topological theory of degree. What one also needs to know (for many practical purposes) is that with sufficient smoothness, topological calculations of degree are in agreement with differential-topological calculations. I would say that this is an exercise if you are very confident with both kinds of degree.

Here is another way of looking at it. Suppose $Y$ is obtained from $X$ by attaching an $n$-cell along the map $f\colon S^n\to X$. By excision (excise $Y\setminus D^{n+1}$ from the pair $(Y,X\cup (D^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}))$ and apply a homotopy equivalence) the characteristic map induces an isomorphism $$H_\ast(D^{n+1},S^n)\cong H_\ast(Y,X),$$
hence there is an exact sequence
$$0\to H_{n+1}(X)\to H_{n+1}(Y)\to \mathbb{Z}\to H_{n}(X)\to H_n(Y)\to 0$$
and in all other degrees $H_i(X)\cong H_i(Y)$.
Suppose $f_\ast(1) = x\in H_n(X)$. By comparing the long exact sequences of the pairs $(D^{n+1},S^n)$ and $(Y,X)$ we see that $\mathbb{Z}\to H_n(X)$ also maps $1$ to $x$. Thus, $H_n(Y)\cong H_n(X)/\langle x\rangle$ and $H_{n+1}(Y)\cong H_{n+1}(X)\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ if $x$ is torsion and $H_{n+1}(Y)\cong H_{n+1}(X)$ of $x$ is not torsion.
